# Spring Security Sample - Works without application context

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to Spring and checked Spring Security. In the Spring website there are links to HelloWorld Spring projects. The project could be imported by Maven and run on Eclipse dev environment. What's interesting about this project is there is no web.xml or context.xml which defines spring configurations.

The project contained two classes, and an index.jsp file.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
// @formatter:off
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws      Exception {`enter code here`
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
    // @formatter:on
}
```

That is the config class, the other is the initializing class.

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

I commented **@EnableWebSecurity** and removed the annotations and assumed that Spring Security would be disabled, but no. When I executed it was looking for filter chain that isn't implemented anywhere.

How could such a thing happen. I even tried cleaning the server work directory and such but still its the same.

Any idea on how this simple project ticks?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot, it automatically configures web security if spring-boot-starter-security is on the classpath.
Please refer:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/#initial

[Spring web security: is @EnableWebSecurity obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36336550/spring-web-security-is-enablewebsecurity-obsolete)

Comment: thanks for the reply. The POM doesn't have Spring Boot dependency in it so the application isn't a Spring Boot application. This is a strange thing, I cannot understand where the Spring related settings are maintained.